# Rebus - Audit Queue and Expiration

Tags: rebus

How is everyone handling the audit queue and not letting the size get out of hand? Is there a concept similar to TimeToBeReceive as with NServiceBus?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you have something consume the messages and store them somewhere cheap - could be a database or the file system if you're running on a local machine, or a bunch of append blobs if you're in Azure.

Then you can always decide what to do about the messages later :)

Comment: i like that idea. :)